# Auto execute shell script during bootup (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell

Are there any folder like /etc/cron.d/, so when I put a script inside this folder, it will get automatically executed during the bootup time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call your script from /etc/rc.local .

Comment: That would require edit the file rc.local, any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Make it an [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) script

Answer (score 1):

> That would require edit the file rc.local, any other way?

If you don't have `sudo` permission, you can create a cron job with something like this:

```
@reboot /path/to/your/script
```